# Templates break http HEAD method

Tags: templates, go

Consider this code: when I GET `http://localhost:8080/` or `http://localhost:8080/foo` everything works as expected. But when I use the HEAD http method, `http://localhost:8080/foo` works but `http://localhost:8080/` breaks (the main program exits and I get this error: 'template: main.html:1:0: executing "main.html" at <"homeHandler">: http: request method or response status code does not allow body'). The difference between those two is the use of the template in one case (`/`) and a simple string in the other(`/foo`).

In my code I use templates extensively, so it looks like I have to ask explicitly for the method and return "200" (or the appropriate code). Is there a way to have templates and the automatic handling of the HEAD method?

I have tried these to test: `curl http://localhost:8080/foo -I` (`-I` for the HEAD method).

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

var (
    templates *template.Template
)

// OK, HEAD + GET work fine
func fooHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("fooHandler"))
}

// GET works fine, HEAD results in an error:
// template: main.html:1:0: executing "main.html" at <"homeHandler">:
//   http: request method or response status code does not allow body
func homeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "main.html", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    var err error
    templates, err = template.ParseGlob("templates/*.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Loading template: ", err)
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/", homeHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/foo", fooHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

The file `main.html` in the subdirectory `templates` is just this string: `homeHandler`

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks"? I've just tested the equivalent of `curl http://localhost:8080/ -I` on one of my Go template driven pages and it returned the `HEAD` info correctly. Is there an error?

Comment: @Intermernet the error is hidden in the code: the program exits and reports the error that the data in the template is not allowed in the HEAD request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is self-explaining:

> request method or response status code does not allow body

A HEAD request only allows HTTP headers to be sent back as response.
The real question is why you are able to write to the body in `fooHandler`.

EDIT:

`fooHandler` won't write anything either, you are omiting the error it is returning which is `http.ErrBodyNotAllowed`.

Comment: That doesn't really help me, I am afraid. I wonder (as you write) why the system ignores the contents written by `w.Write()` and not by `ExecuteTemplate()`. My question is more or less: what is the best way to make code "HEAD safe"

Comment: See the edition I made to the answer. As to making it HEAD safe; test for `http.ErrBodyNotAllowed`

Comment: Note to self: never, never, never ignore the returning error... Thanks!